# Push notification using WebView and Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I was wondering if it's possible in a WebView application to send push notifications with javascript on the external page?

(Say I have example.com/news, is it possible to send a push notification if a function is sent?)

Thanks!

Comment: wut? you want to send notification from your webview to server? or receive notification from server?

Comment: @VladimirM receive from server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you may use web sockets to get the notifications. However, with mobile devices, there native side has way better support when it comes to handling notifications with respect to the device state.

So In my opinion, your best approach is to handle the push notifications in native code and communicate it to the webview via Javascript bridge.

Comment: I'll try that. If it works I'll mark it as accepted.